# Git workflow for performing code reviews on AWS CodeCommit on master branch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codecommit

We have a codebase that was mostly developed by a single person over 2 or 3 years. It's mostly all commits to master. We're now going to add some additional people to the team, and now that there are other people, we'd like to review eachother's code.

We're using AWS CodeCommit for source control. AWS recommends doing pull requests here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codecommit-pull-requests-to-request-code-reviews-and-discuss-code/

As we've been developing on master, we were wondering if there are any other mechanisms for doing code reviews without introducing feature branches?

Comment: I'm aware that git itself does not have code reviews, please don't be so pedantic as to be unhelpful.

And code reviews need not necessarily involve branches. For example I could use patches to drive reviews, and that would _not_ require branching.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **Continuous Integration** (CI).

According to Dave Farley, it means little, or no branching (dividing up the work and working on separate pieces independently). Instead we make small changes to Trunk, or Master, and continuously evaluate them. If branches exist at all, they are tiny and short-lived, no longer than a day.

His [Continuous Delivery](https://www.youtube.com/@ContinuousDelivery) channel on YouTube has a playlist called [Continuous Integration, Pull Requests & Branching](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwLLcwQlnXBwYldncW6PcnscoqiFsH7un).

It may give you some guidance on how to work effectively without getting bogged down with branches.

The only thing I can say to watch out for with CodeCommit is the lack of communication features that you might have come to expect from other systems such as GitHub or BitBucket. Notifications and such are possible, but you would need to build them yourself using other services such as SNS. If you must use CodeCommit, then I wish you patience :-)